# Can't connect to smb 1.0

Tags: samba, cifs

I am a newbie Kubuntu 22.04 x64 user.
I have kernel version: Linux 6.2.0-31-generic x86_64.

I have 2 houses, and i installed on both PCs the same OS version (same ISO):
a) PC Desktop + NAS running with SMB1 (Buffalo Linkstation).
b) notebook + another NAS with SMB1 (another Buffalo Linkstation, but older model than location above)

From command line, i need to connect to NAS shares.

In location "a", after some tris i finally can connect to my share with this command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.6/development /nas/development -o username=wout,password=xxxxxxxx,domain=MSHOME,vers=1.0
```

and i can connect without problems.
(Next step will be use a credentials file instead of user/pass in command)

In location "b", with older NAS, using *smb4K* i can connect to my nas using Dolphin, but i really can't find how to make the command above to work. It's been one week I am hammering my head on this notebook, but any result.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.6/development /nas/development -o username=wout,password=xxxxxxxx,domain=MSHOME,vers=1.0
```

Has result:

> `mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.2.6,unc=\\192.168.2.6\development,vers=1.0,user=wout,domain=MSHOME,pass=******** mount error(22): Invalid argument Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)`

This is the output of: *tail -f  /var/log/kern.log* :

```
Sep  3 15:42:40 wout kernel: [ 2807.010994] CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old servers

Sep  3 15:42:40 wout kernel: [ 2807.011003] CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.2.6\sviluppo

Sep  3 15:42:40 wout kernel: [ 2807.034540] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22
```

I tried to modify */etc/samba/smb.conf*

```
   workgroup = MSHOME
   min protocol = CORE
   client min protocol = NT1
   server min protocol = NT1
```

But any result: Dolphin works fine, but from command line I can't connect and the kernel.log isn't helping too much as it does not write which argument is wrong.

I tried to change position of arguments, mount folder, nas path,.. nothing

I tried the command *modprobe cifs disable_legacy_dialects=n*

Is there anyone who can kindly help me giving some advices, please?

I red almost every post about this problem but i can't find a solution, maybe there is something missing in my installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In location "b", with older NAS, using smb4K i can connect to my nas
> using Dolphin, but i really can't find how to make the command above
> to work. It's been one week I am hammering my head on this notebook,
> but any result.
>
> ```
> sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.6/development /nas/development -o username=wout,password=xxxxxxxx,domain=MSHOME,vers=1.0
> ```

Add another option to your mount declatation: **nodfs**

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.2.6/development /nas/development -o username=wout,password=xxxxxxxx,domain=MSHOME,vers=1.0,nodfs
```

Better?

Comment: Thank you very much @Morbius1, it works! Reading what this parameter stands for, I really couldn't think that this would be the solution. You are very good!