# Ubuntu 22.04: mount.cifs stopped working with vers=1.0,sec=ntlmv2 after upgrades

Tags: upgrade, mount, samba, cifs

I used to mount an old NAS (QNAP TS-101) via `/etc/fstab` as `cifs` with the options `vers=1.0,sec=ntlmv2` (these were the only options working for this network disk with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). However, after recent upgrades, it stopped working and returns `mount error(22): Invalid argument`.

I tried to play with different combinations of `vers` and `sec` options (as recommended in different posts), but nothing works. The regression happened some time between July and September 2023 (I didn't mount the disk regularly, so I cannot pinpoint the exact upgrade that broke it).

Has anybody encountered the same issue? Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to smb 1.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484559/cant-connect-to-smb-1-0)

Comment: Should be voted as a duplicate of the answer that is linked below.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer here:

[Can't connect to smb 1.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484559/cant-connect-to-smb-1-0)

Adding option `nodfs` solves the problem.